# checkbox combination selection shiny R

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I am trying to use shiny checkbox for selecting different views. Each combination of checkbox has a separate view (qplot view with a different dataframe). My server code is getting convoluted and I'm wondering if, because I'm new to this, I'm missing a much simpler way of doing this. Also, when I select all three options, the correct view doesn't show up - it works when I just put in 2 options.

Here is my UI.R code:

```
hr(),
h5(textOutput("Select Followers & Unfollowers View")),
checkboxInput("check_followers", label = h6("Followers"), value = FALSE),
checkboxInput("check_unfollowers", label = h6("Unfollowers"), value = FALSE),
checkboxInput("check_diff", label = h6("Followers minus unfollowers"), value = FALSE),
```

Here is my server.R code:

```
  if (input$check_followers == TRUE) { 
    if(input$check_unfollowers == TRUE){
      if (input$check_diff == TRUE) {

      ## plot for all 3  cumulative
        plot_SaleTrends <-  qplot(month, count, data= cumsum_foll_unfoll_diff_merge, color=type,  xlab="month", ylab="Count", geom ="line")

        # if checkbox to add trend line to plot
        if (input$trendlineselect == TRUE) {
          plot_SaleTrends <- plot_SaleTrends + 
            geom_smooth(method=loess, span=input$trendline_sen_sel, level=as.numeric(input$trendline_conf_sel))
        }
      }


        ## plot for follower and unfollow cumulative
        plot_SaleTrends <- qplot(month, count, data= foll_unfoll_cumsub, color=type,  xlab="month", ylab="Count", geom ="line")
        # if checkbox to add trend line to plot
        if (input$trendlineselect == TRUE) {
          plot_SaleTrends <- plot_SaleTrends + 
            geom_smooth(method=loess, span=input$trendline_sen_sel, level=as.numeric(input$trendline_conf_sel))

      }}

     else if (input$check_diff == TRUE){
        ## plot follower and diff cumulative 
       plot_SaleTrends <- qplot(month, count, data= diff_foll_cumsub, color=type,  xlab="month", ylab="Count", geom ="line")
       # if checkbox to add trend line to plot
       if (input$trendlineselect == TRUE) {
         plot_SaleTrends <- plot_SaleTrends + 
           geom_smooth(method=loess, span=input$trendline_sen_sel, level=as.numeric(input$trendline_conf_sel))
       }
     }
        ## plot just for follower cumulative 
         plot_SaleTrends <-  qplot(month, count, data= foll_cumsub, color=type,  xlab="month", ylab="Count", geom ="line")
        # if checkbox to add trend line to plot
         if (input$trendlineselect == TRUE) {
              plot_SaleTrends <- plot_SaleTrends + 
         geom_smooth(method=loess, span=input$trendline_sen_sel, level=as.numeric(input$trendline_conf_sel))


      }

  }



 if (input$check_unfollowers == TRUE) { # unfollower
   if (input$check_followers == TRUE) { 
     if (input$check_diff == TRUE) {
       ## plot all 3
       plot_SaleTrends <-  qplot(month, count, data= cumsum_foll_unfoll_diff_merge, color=type,  xlab="month", ylab="Count", geom ="line")

       # if checkbox to add trend line to plot
       if (input$trendlineselect == TRUE) {
         plot_SaleTrends <- plot_SaleTrends + 
           geom_smooth(method=loess, span=input$trendline_sen_sel, level=as.numeric(input$trendline_conf_sel))
       }

     }
     # plot follower and unfollower
     plot_SaleTrends <- qplot(month, count, data= foll_unfoll_cumsub, color=type,  xlab="month", ylab="Count", geom ="line")
     # if checkbox to add trend line to plot
     if (input$trendlineselect == TRUE) {
       plot_SaleTrends <- plot_SaleTrends + 
         geom_smooth(method=loess, span=input$trendline_sen_sel, level=as.numeric(input$trendline_conf_sel))
     }
   }
  else if (input$check_diff == TRUE){
       #plot unfollow and diff
    plot_SaleTrends <-  qplot(month, count, data= diff_unfoll_cumsub, color=type,  xlab="month", ylab="Count", geom ="line")
    # if checkbox to add trend line to plot
    if (input$trendlineselect == TRUE) {
      plot_SaleTrends <- plot_SaleTrends + 
        geom_smooth(method=loess, span=input$trendline_sen_sel, level=as.numeric(input$trendline_conf_sel))
    }
  }
   else{
     #plot unfollow only
     plot_SaleTrends <- qplot(month, count, data= unfoll_cumsub, color=type,  xlab="month", ylab="Count", geom ="line")
     # if checkbox to add trend line to plot
     if (input$trendlineselect == TRUE) {
       plot_SaleTrends <- plot_SaleTrends + 
         geom_smooth(method=loess, span=input$trendline_sen_sel, level=as.numeric(input$trendline_conf_sel))
     }

   }
   }
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: It seems that no matter what others inputs are selected the `input$trendlineselect` always determines the same thing. You could use only one if-clause related to this input at the end outside all other if-clauses.

Comment: I, thanks - I changed to radio buttons and it became much easier to manage. There were just too many options. And what I should have done was just change variables and then create a dynamic plot at the end. Cheers, Mari